# css/js local vs remote minified

Tags: javascript, html, css

My html index page includes not-minified js/css libraries that I use and edit in local. I need that the remote version includes rather the minified one/concatenated one, so, basically, I need to have a different head between local and remote version.

Is there any best practice to do this?

**html i want in local**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="script1.js"/></script>
  <script src="script2.js"/></script>
  <script src="script3.js"/></script>
</head>
```

**html I want in remote**

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="script123.min.js" /></script>
</head>
```

script123 includes 1,2 and 3 concatenated and minified.
I thought I could simply push an index.html on remote and then gitignore it, but it looks so awful even because I use to edit very often my index.

Comment: use grunt or gulp

Comment: If you use a server-side technology, then you can deploy different configurations allowing you to do this. If you are using HTML only, then it will depend on your deployment tools and if there is any way to script the changes during deployment. If not, then you have to make the change manually before deployment.

Comment: I'm using gulp actually, but I still cannot figure out how to use it for that purpose

Comment: Why do you want to have separated files locally? So that it is easier to debug? If so then you might want to check sourcemap files.

Comment: So it is faster to edit and try, without re-concatenate/minify everything every time. After the code is stable/works I will gulp all this and push it in remote

Comment: Using webpack as build tool and its watch option, will compile and minifiy the files at the time they are changed.

Comment: I will try that, Thank you